# Displaying random images from an array

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have created an array which contains 2 images, I want to show these images randomly (so one shows then when the page is refreshed a different show, etc) I have re-used code i used a long time ago and it doesn't seem to be working could someone help me with where i am going wrong please.

```
<?php
$images = array(
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/man_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>',
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/woman_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>'
        );

shuffle($images); // Randomize images array;
?>
<img class="succes_img" src="\$images[]\" >
```

I dont understand where it is going wrong but on the front end it show an image with the broken link sign in it,

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look at arrays and echo in PHP - it will very quickly be clear whats wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a basic PHP usage question, not Magento specific.

Comment: ok thank @jonathanHussey, would you like me to move it to normal stackoverflow or just keep it in mind for next time?

Comment: This is really just for Magento specific questions so by all means post on SO if you are not able to determine the issue yourself - I'm sure you will get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code instead:

```
<?php
$images = array(
    '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/man_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>',
    '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/woman_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>'
);
shuffle($images); // Randomize images array;
echo $images[0];
?>
```